# What are some APIs that write transactions to the blockchain?

Tags: transactions, external-api, transfer

Are there any APIs that write transactions to the blockchain?

I am most interested in RESTful versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many services to interact with the blockchain -

Infura https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ethereum/json-rpc-methods

Alchemy https://www.alchemy.com/

Also

- Kaleido.
- Amazon Managed Blockchain
- Azure Blockchain Workbench
- IBM Blockchain Platform
- Chainstack
- BlockCypher
- Luniverse